# Recursive search and filtering in a menu

Tags: angular, typescript, recursion, search, filter

I have an angular app that I'm working on.
my problem is this:
I have a navigation menu on the side with the option to search inside the menu.
this is the **JSON** for the menu:

```
menuItems: [
{
    name: "Dashboard",
    iconPath: "Dash@board.png",
    routingPath: "",
    children: [
        {
            name: "Version 1",
            iconPath: "",
            routingPath: "",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Version 1.1 abc",
                    iconPath: "",
                    routingPath: "",
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "Version 1.1.1 ccc",
                            iconPath: "",
                            routingPath: "",
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "Version 1.1.1.1 hello",
                                    iconPath: "",
                                    routingPath: "",
                                    children: []
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Version 1.1.2.1",
                                    iconPath: "",
                                    routingPath: "",
                                    children: []
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Version 1.1.3.1 sdfsdf",
                                    iconPath: "",
                                    routingPath: "",
                                    children: []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Version 1.1.2",
                            iconPath: "",
                            routingPath: "",
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Version 1.1.3",
                            iconPath: "",
                            routingPath: "",
                            children: []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Version 1.2",
                    iconPath: "",
                    routingPath: "",
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Version 2",
            iconPath: "",
            routingPath: "",
            children: []
        },
        {
            name: "Version 3",
            iconPath: "",
            routingPath: "",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Version 3.1",
                    iconPath: "",
                    routingPath: "",
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    name: "Version 3.2",
                    iconPath: "",
                    routingPath: "",
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    name: "Version 3.3",
                    iconPath: "",
                    routingPath: "",
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "Pages",
    iconPath: "Pa@ges.png",
    routingPath: "",
    children: [
        {
            name: "ZZZ Page 1",
            iconPath: "",
            routingPath: "",
            children: []
        }
    ]
},]
```

this is an example for the menu.
what I'm trying to achieve is this:
if someone searches hello, I need to display this (I Only display the name but I need all of the data inside the object):

[image]

But it doesn't work.
I have tried this code:

```
private performFiltering() {
    const searchValue: string = this.searchBarInput.nativeElement.value.toLowerCase();

    if (searchValue.length > 0) {
        this.filteredMenu.menuItems = this.fullMenu.menuItems.filter((item) => {
            return this.recursiveSearchInMenu(item, searchValue);
        });
}}

private recursiveSearchInMenu(menu: MenuItemModel, searchValue) {
    let found = menu.children.find((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue));
    if (!found) {
        let i = 0;
        while (!found && i < menu.children.length) {
            if (menu.children[i].children && menu.children[i].children.length) {
                found = this.recursiveSearchInMenu(menu.children[i], searchValue);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

This is my result:
[image]

any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it...

this is my current answer:

```
private performFiltering(): boolean {
    const searchValue: string = this.searchBarInput.nativeElement.value.toLowerCase();
    const isFiltered = searchValue.length > 0;

    this.showSearchButton(isFiltered);

    if (isFiltered) {
        this.filteredMenu.menuItems = this.recursiveSearchInMenu(
            JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.fullMenu.menuItems)),
            searchValue
        );
    } else {
        this.filteredMenu.menuItems = this.fullMenu.menuItems;
    }

    return isFiltered;
}

private recursiveSearchInMenu(menuItems: MenuItemModel[], searchValue: string): MenuItemModel[] {
    const matchingMenuItems: MenuItemModel[] = [];

    menuItems.forEach((menuItem) => {
        if (menuItem.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)) {
            matchingMenuItems.push(menuItem);
        } else {
            const matchingChildren = this.recursiveSearchInMenu(menuItem.children, searchValue);

            if (matchingChildren.length > 0) {
                menuItem.children = matchingChildren;
                matchingMenuItems.push(menuItem);
            }
        }
    });

    return matchingMenuItems;
}
```

if you have any suggestions on how to improve it I would love to get your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your problem correct - your code from example will not work, because this.fullMenu.menuItems.filter will filter only parent object(Dashboard) without filtering content of this objects.
You can create function like recursiveSearchInMenu that will build array with filtered options (add one more hash variable which will store child objects that was found)
*Something like that.*

```
private recursiveSearchInMenu(menu: MenuItemModel, searchValue) {
    let result = [];
    let found = menu.children.find((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue));
    if(found)
    {
        result.add(found);
    }else {
        let i = 0;
        while (!found && i < menu.children.length) {
            if (menu.children[i].children && menu.children[i].children.length) {
                found = this.recursiveSearchInMenu(menu.children[i], searchValue);  
                if(found.Length > 0) {
                    result.add({name: menu.children[i].name,
                    iconPath: menu.children[i].iconPath,
                    routingPath : menu.children[i].routingPath,
                    children: found})
                }
            i++;
         }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Including the code for your suggested function would make your answer much more useful.